# Ranking values by group and hours (timestamp)

Tags: r, database, date, timestamp, rank

Here is an exemple of my database :

| ID_user | ID_session | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | S451 | 2023-02-06 12:02:03 |
| ID1 | S489 | 2023-02-06 11:55:06 |
| ID2 | S123 | 2023-02-06 11:57:06 |
| ID2 | S456 | 2023-02-06 14:57:06 |

etc...

I would like to rank ID_session by ID_user and by date, hours, minutes.

Example :

| ID_user | ID_session | Timestamp | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | S451 | 2023-02-06 12:02:03 | 2 |
| ID1 | S489 | 2023-02-06 11:55:06 | 1 |
| ID2 | S123 | 2023-02-06 11:57:06 | 1 |
| ID2 | S456 | 2023-02-06 14:57:06 | 2 |

Do you think its possible on Rstudio ?

I've tried order function, but it didn't work. Same with arrange, rank... It seems hours and minutes aren't selected.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using ? is it mysql ?

Answer (score 0):

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
quux %>%
  group_by(ID_user) %>%
  mutate(rank = dense_rank(Timestamp)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 4 × 4
#   ID_user ID_session Timestamp            rank
#   <chr>   <chr>      <chr>               <int>
# 1 ID1     S451       2023-02-06 12:02:03     2
# 2 ID1     S489       2023-02-06 11:55:06     1
# 3 ID2     S123       2023-02-06 11:57:06     1
# 4 ID2     S456       2023-02-06 14:57:06     2
```

## base R

```r
quux$rank <- as.integer(ave(quux$Timestamp, quux$ID_user, FUN = rank, ties.method = "first"))
quux
#   ID_user ID_session           Timestamp rank
# 1     ID1       S451 2023-02-06 12:02:03    2
# 2     ID1       S489 2023-02-06 11:55:06    1
# 3     ID2       S123 2023-02-06 11:57:06    1
# 4     ID2       S456 2023-02-06 14:57:06    2
```

## data.table

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(quux)[, rank := frank(Timestamp), by = .(ID_user)]
#    ID_user ID_session           Timestamp  rank
#     <char>     <char>              <char> <num>
# 1:     ID1       S451 2023-02-06 12:02:03     2
# 2:     ID1       S489 2023-02-06 11:55:06     1
# 3:     ID2       S123 2023-02-06 11:57:06     1
# 4:     ID2       S456 2023-02-06 14:57:06     2
```

## SQL

```r
sqldf::sqldf("
  select ID_user, ID_session, Timestamp,
    rank() over (partition by ID_user order by Timestamp) as rank
  from quux")
#   ID_user ID_session           Timestamp rank
# 1     ID1       S489 2023-02-06 11:55:06    1
# 2     ID1       S451 2023-02-06 12:02:03    2
# 3     ID2       S123 2023-02-06 11:57:06    1
# 4     ID2       S456 2023-02-06 14:57:06    2
```

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(ID_user = c("ID1", "ID1", "ID2", "ID2"), ID_session = c("S451", "S489", "S123", "S456"), Timestamp = c("2023-02-06 12:02:03", "2023-02-06 11:55:06", "2023-02-06 11:57:06", "2023-02-06 14:57:06")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```